# helm function does not work as expected with append

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Trying to define a function in _helpers.tpl such that on a given values file, the function outputs a list with all elements names that contains the key `serviceOwner`.
Then call this function from a configMap object.

This is the value-services.yaml file:

```
services:
  - name: element1
    serviceOwner: microsoft
    revision: 1.0.31
  - name: element2
    revision: 1.0.35
```

This is the function I defined in _helpers.tpl :

```
{{- define "configMapsList" -}}
  {{- $configMaps := list }}
  {{- range $service := .Values.services }}
    {{- if hasKey $service "serviceOwner" }}
      {{- $configMaps = $configMaps | append $service.name }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- $configMaps }}
{{- end }}
```

And this is the configMap object where I call the function:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: "test-cm"
    namespace: my-namespace
data:
  key: "{{ include "configMapsList" . | join "," }}"
```

**I expect to get a list that contains `[element1]` because it’s the only element that contains a `serviceOwner`** . But instead I get the following error:

```
.... error calling include: template: router/templates/_helpers.tpl:16:38: executing "configMapsList" at <append $service.name>: error calling append: Cannot push on type string
```

Any suggestion what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

error from https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/581758eb7d96ae4d113649668fa96acc74d46e7f/list.go#L42

should be something like

```
{{- define "configMapsList" -}}
  {{- $configMaps := list }}
  {{- range $service := .Values.services }}
    {{- if hasKey $service "serviceOwner" }}
      {{- $configMaps = append $configMaps $service.name }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- $configMaps }}
{{- end }}
```

output

```
# Source: test/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: "test-cm"
    namespace: my-namespace
data:
  key: "[element1]"
```

depends on how it should looks like

see [documentation](https://github.com/Masterminds/sprig/blob/581758eb7d96ae4d113649668fa96acc74d46e7f/docs/lists.md#append-mustappend)